# How can I rewrite specific URLs on an existing site to load pages from WordPress which is installed in a subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an existing site built with CodeIgniter at example.com.

I have a WordPress install at example.com/wp. Urls look like this: example.com/wp/my-page

I'm trying to figure out how I can rewrite example.com/my-page  to display the contents of the example.com/wp/my-page while still displaying the URL as example.com/my-page.

CodeIgniter controls the index.php file, so I can't use WordPress's index.php in the root.

I'm half way there, I have it working with a plain HTML file, but getting WordPress involved rewrites the url to the /wp subdirectory.

Here's what I'm using, in the example.com root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^my-page /wp/my-page [P]

</IfModule>
```

When I visit example.com/my-page I end up at example/wp.

I imagine it has something to do with the standard WordPress .htaccess in the /wp/ directory which looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried adding the [P] flag to the WordPress rules but no luck, I also tried not setting the rewrite base to /wp/.

The problem is I don't understand this stuff in enough detail to figure out my issue, or to know whether this is possible.

In summary, I think I'm trying to rewrite a rewritten URL without doing a redirect (hence the [P] flags).

Can this be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `P`? You use **mod_proxy**? `L` flag stops rules execution

Comment: My mistake. Doesn't seem to work as I want with L flag either, which is why I tried to use the mod_proxy option.

Comment: What exactly does not work when you use `L` on the rule `RewriteRule ^my-page /wp/my-page [L]` ? (without changing wordpress rules).

Comment: I just tried this, and i see `/my-page` in uri, but the request really hits `/wp/index.php` , and it gets `REQUEST_URI=/my-page` and `REDIRECT_URL]=/wp/my-page`

Comment: It gets redirected fully to mysite.com/wp/my-page, the URI in the address bar changes.

Comment: Right, my mistake. It works when I use the same page name. I can't redirect mysite.com/page-b to mysite.com/wp/page-a but I can redirect mysite.com/page-a to mysite.com/wp/page-a. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$ cat .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^my-page wp/my-page [L]
```

**$ tree -a wp**

```
wp
|-- .htaccess
`-- index.php
```

**$ cat wp/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**$ cat wp/index.php**

```
<pre><?php print_r($_SERVER); ?></pre>
```

---

Result:

URL visible in browser: `http://example.com/my-page`
Output:

```
Array
(
[REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[HTTP_HOST] => example.com
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us,en;q=0.5
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 80
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
[SERVER_NAME] => example.com
[SERVER_ADDR] => 1.2.3.4
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 4.3.2.1
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /www/vhosts/example.com/
[SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@example.com
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /www/vhosts/example.com/wp/index.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 57775
[REDIRECT_URL] => /wp/my-page
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /my-page
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /wp/index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /wp/index.php
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1342091732
)
```

---

So, if you're still seeing a redirect after this point, that is being done by wordpress **php code**

Comment: Yep. This is bang on. Thank you.